# Getting unknown column id on stored procedure call

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have following stored procedure to reset auto increments for a table that gets many inserts and deletes.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS reset_autoincrement;
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE PROCEDURE reset_autoincrement(IN tableName VARCHAR(250))
BEGIN
      SELECT @max :=  MAX(`id`) + 1 + concat(' FROM ', tableName ); 
      set @alter_statement = concat('ALTER TABLE ', tableName ,' AUTO_INCREMENT = ', @max);
      PREPARE stmt FROM @alter_statement;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$;
```

and call it with

```
call reset_autoincrement('queueIn');
```

and get

> 23:18:25  call reset_autoincrement('queueIn') Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'   0,042 sec

A little excerpt of the table's columns:

```
id  bigint(19) UN AI PK
created_at  timestamp
updated_at  timestamp
```

I have two questions.

1. Obviously ... why do I get this error - the column clearly is there.
2. The id column gets incremented to a million within 6 hours, there are many insert/delete operations throughout the day. Is there an even better way to reset auto_increments in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are trying to make it a dynamic query (the below line) and as it stands currently it's a mixture of dynamic and normal query.

```
SELECT @max :=  MAX(`id`) + 1 + concat(' FROM ', tableName );
```

You should make it a dynamic query fully

```
SET @sql = "SELECT MAX(`id`) + 1 FROM " + tableName;
```

You would need to hold the variable from first dynamic query and use it in `ALTER` statement. Something like below

```
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE PROCEDURE reset_autoincrement(IN tableName VARCHAR(250))
BEGIN
      SET @var1 = 0;
      SET @sql = "SELECT MAX(`id`) + 1 INTO @var1 FROM " + tableName; 
      PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      SET @ID = @var1;
      set @alter_statement = concat('ALTER TABLE ', tableName ,' AUTO_INCREMENT = ', @ID);
      PREPARE stmt FROM @alter_statement;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$;
```

Comment: May I ask, is this the recommended way to reset it? Or is there somewhat better?

Comment: @J.Doe, not sure why you are using a dynamic query and why not just directly reset the AUTO_INCREMENT. If you want the tablename to be dynamic like what you are doing then probably yes a dynamic query (OR) check with informationSchema_Tables. Also, see edited answer to have it work fully.

Comment: There are multiple tables that get that amount of data, one for every country, so I thought a dynamic query would be the best fit. I'm not really sure what you mean with _check with informationSchema-Tables_, but that might be due to my not knowing about informationSchema, but I'll google it. Thank you very much for your help, I tried it with your updated query and it does what it should, I'll have a read at the documentation about what you mentioned.